# Merging multiple lines by key in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to do some analysis on a table of events with different parameters which are stored as key/value pairs.

I have ended up with a data frame as follows:

```
event <- c("event1", "event2", "event3", "event1", "event2", "event2", "event3")
url.key <- c("url_A", "url_A", "url_A", "url_B", "url_B", "url_C", "url_C")
url.value <- c("url_1", "url_2", "url_3", "url_3", "url_4", "url_5", "url_5")
refr.key <- c("", "ref_A", "ref_B", "ref_C", "ref_D", "", "ref_D")
refr.value <- c("", "ref_1", "ref_2", "", "ref_3", "", "ref_3")


df <- tibble(event, url.key, url.value, refr.key, refr.value)
df %>% spread(url.key, url.value) %>% spread(refr.key, refr.value) 

#Result
 event url_A url_B url_C    `` ref_A ref_B ref_C ref_D
 *  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 event1 url_1  <NA>  <NA>        <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
 2 event1  <NA> url_3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>        <NA>
 3 event2 url_2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> ref_1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
 4 event2  <NA> url_4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> ref_3
 5 event2  <NA>  <NA> url_5        <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
 6 event3 url_3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> ref_2  <NA>  <NA>
 7 event3  <NA>  <NA> url_5  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> ref_3
```

What I want to do is merge the lines together by key, so that there is one line per event, as follows:

```
   event url_A url_B url_C    `` ref_A ref_B ref_C ref_D
*  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 event1 url_1 url_3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2 event2 url_2 url_4  url_5 <NA> ref_1  <NA>  <NA>  ref_3
3 event3 url_3  <NA>  url_5 <NA> <NA>  ref_2  <NA>  ref_3
```

How would I achieve this with dplyr or similar?  The actual dataset is very wide with an arbitrary number of key/value pairs, so anything which requires naming the columns in advance won't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df %>% 
  spread(url.key, url.value) %>% 
  spread(refr.key, refr.value) %>%  
  select(-5) %>% 
  group_by(event) %>% 
  summarise_all(function(.x) .x %>% na.omit %>% toString)
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you!

Please could you explain the syntax of (function(.x) .x %>% na.omit %>% toString)  or point me to somewhere I can look it up?

Comment: `summarize_all` takes a function as argument. `summarize_all(max) `would apply `max` to each grouped column. Here @Dan defined an anonymous inline function using the same dplyr piping %>%. This would be the same as defining something like `myFunc <- function(z) {toString(na.omit(z))}` and then doing `summarise_all(myFunc)`

Comment: Yep, so each column (except event, which is grouped) comes in as a vector (`.x`), then we get rid of the `NA` values and make it a string.